# How to solve issue with insert function of f# trees

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

Please, I need some help with creating an insert function for a tree. The value in a given string list should be inserted to every branch and leaf in a tree. I have tried to solve this issue and have a very close answer but I am not able to write the function correctly to insert all the string values.

Code:

```
type Tree = Leaf of string | Branch of (string * Tree) list

let rec insertTree (lst : string list) (tree : Tree) : Tree =

        match lst, tree with
        | a::b::c::[], y  -> 
            match y with
            | Leaf(n) -> Branch[(a, Branch[(n, Leaf(c))])]
            | Branch[(x, p)] -> Branch[(x, Branch[(a, Branch[(b, insertTree (c::[]) p)])])]
            | _     -> insertTree (b::c::[]) y
        | _ , y    -> tree
```

Test: `insertTree ["4"; "5";"6"] (Branch [("1", (Branch[("2", Leaf("3"))]))])`

Gives: `Branch [("1", Branch [("4", Branch [("5", Branch [("2", Leaf "3")])])])]`

I want this instead:

```
(Branch [("1", (Branch[("2", (Branch[("3",(Branch[("4",(Branch[("5", Leaf("6"))]))]))]))]))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you just want to append the list in order to the final leaf and that all branches will have at most a single element in its list.

```
let insertTree (lst : string list) (tree : Tree) : Tree =
    let rec insertSingleIntotree x t = 
        match t with
        | Leaf(n) -> Branch[(n,Leaf x)]
        | Branch[(n,p)] -> Branch[(n, insertSingleIntotree x p)]
        | _ -> failwith "no idea what should happen here!"

    lst
    |> List.fold (fun acc x -> insertSingleIntotree x acc) tree
```

Comment: Yes! Ringil this is what I wanted. Thanks a lot.